# vertical-align not working in my table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use an asterisk.
by default they are somewhat aligned to be on top (hello*****)
I am using vertical-align:sub and its not working, i think it has to do maybe i am also using text align right?

```html
        <table cellspacing="0"style="border-spacing:0;">
            <tr style="line-height:15px;">
              <td style="width:30%;">C</td>
              <td style="text-align:right;vertical-align:sub;">*****</td>
            </tr>
             <tr style="line-height:15px;">
               <td>C+++</td>
               <td style="text-align:right;">*****</td>
            </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height:15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align:right">****</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="line-height:15px;">
              <td>C#</td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">***</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="line-height:15px;">
              <td>Javascript</td>
              <td style="text-align:right">**</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="line-height:15px;">
              <td>Python</td>
              <td style="text-align:right;">*</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think asterisk is "aligned" to be on top. It's just a character designed that way. If you want it to be at the bottom, you can try the following.

```css
table tr {
  line-height:15px;
}
table tr td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
table tr td:last-child span {
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: -7px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td><span>*****</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C+++</td>
    <td><span>*****</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Java</td>
    <td><span>****</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C#</td>
    <td><span>***</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Javascript</td>
    <td><span>**</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Python</td>
    <td><span>*</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```